# supress error messages sent to console?

Tags: terminal, logs

How can I suppress error messages sent to a console?

On: Ubuntu? Fedora? Debian? CentOS? RedHat?

Answer (score 3):

Edit the configuration of your syslog daemon: `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, `/etc/syslog-ng.conf` or similar. Look for "console".

Answer (score 1):

```
command 2>/dev/null
```

for all distributions and even other unixes.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm searching for kernel.printk like solutions, so that "logging/warnings" will not occur to console

Comment: then you should edit your question to make that clear